# placing markers in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery

My assignment asks to place multiple markers on the map based on an xml document that we need to parse. I've done the parsing, but I'm having from trouble figuring out how to put the lat and long elements into the new marker object. My code:

```
function loadPoint(){
// var newHTML= "<div style=\"padding:5px;border:solid 1px red\">";
// new_lat =  escapeText($(this).find("latitude").number();
// new_long =  escapeText($(this).find("longitude"));
// newHTML += new_lat + "," + new_long;
// newHTML += "</div>";
// $("body").append(newHTML);

var latlong= new google.maps.LatLng($(this).find("latitude"),$(this).find("longitude"));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: latlong
    })
}

function parser(data) {
$(data).find("item title").each(loadDescription);
$(data).find("item latitude").each(loadLat);
$(data).find("item longitude").each(loadLong);
$(data).find("item").each(loadPoint);
}


function myBadLoadFunction(myXMLHttpRequest,myErrorMessage,myErrorThrown) {
alert('status: ' + myErrorMessage + '\n' + myXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
}

var map;
var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(53.608803,-1.497327);

function initializeMap(){
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: centerPoint,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

 map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas').get(0), myOptions);
```

In my head this makes sense...putting the parsed data as the params for creating a new latlng, but it does nothing so..

Answer (score 0):

Try arranging your declarations first.

```
        var map; //declare it here

        function initialize(){
        var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 16,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  center: centerPoint
                };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
        }
        function loadPoint(){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                map: map
            });

        }
```

Comment: So moving loadPoint() below initialize().... It might look better, but I'm pretty sure that does't fix my issue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      [-33.890542, 151.274856],
      [-33.923036, 151.259052],
      [-34.028249, 151.157507],
      [-33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      [-33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```